# EXCEL - formula used in Evaluate() always returns a VarType 10 (Error), when it works well in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I got to generate via VBA a String that is meant to be an Array formula.

The resulting String is:

```
=SI($B$15:$B$18=Hoja1!$B$4;SI($F$15:$F$18="";$A$15:$A$18))
```

I have like that cause it is in spanish, so you would have to change **SI** for **IF**, **;** for **,** for the formula to work on english localization.

Anyway, when i enter the same generated formula copy/pasted in a cell it works fine, but when I use the Application.Evaluate function in VBA id dows't work.
**VarType** Always returns the value *10* when I analize what **Evaluate** is returning.

I tried everything, debuggind, and can't find what the problem is, maybe there is something wrong inside the string that Evaluate() can't handle well?

Comment: Try `IF` and `,` instead. In the "backend", like from your VBA's perspective, the formulae are always English.

Comment: You can also try the macro recorder (see tip #2 [here](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/writing-formulas-with-macros/)) to see what code it generates when you put this formula into a cell.

Comment: `Application.Evaluate` uses the ActiveSheet context, so if you need this formula evaluated on a specific sheet you should use the `Worksheet.Evaluate` version.

Comment: I know when setting cell formulas from VBA you need to use the US version of the formula - I don't know if that's also the case when using Evaluate, but you could test it.  Can you run a simpler local-format formula using Evaluate?

Comment: @TimWilliams It looke like using a US version of the formula, using IF and changing the semicolon for a simple coma did the job.

Comment: @CherryDT - sorry I see you made the same suggestion ahead of me...